# DataTables 1.9.4 export columns using custom text instead of actual sTitle used

Tags: jquery, datatables

For some of my columns, instead of a text I am currently using an image like:

```
"sTitle": '<img src="/images/image.png" style="max-width:none;" />'
```

Now, for my export I use:

```
"aButtons": [
{
    "sExtends": "xls",
    "sButtonText": "&nbsp;",
    "sTitle": "DashboardExport",
    "sToolTip": "Export visible results to Excel",
    "mColumns": "visible"
}
]
```

And when my xls gets exported, the columns that have image instead of text have a blank name. How can I set a text for those specific columns, as I haven't been able to find this in the docs .. since this is an older version?

Thank you

Comment: Please add a code snippet on how you initialize the datatable,

Comment: @samabcde I would do that, but the initialization has somewhere around 4k lines of code :) It has a ton of options to list the tabs, the filters, and so on, and some may be sensitive information. I can add maybe a more specific part, where the titles are set or something